# Implementing Rooms in Android studio without Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Im trying to use Rooms in my android application to save Cart information for my Food delivery app. Ive been trying to set it up using the documentation https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room#java but none of the [set up code](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room#setup) seems to work. I think its because my build.gradle file is in Java and not Kotlin. I've also tried converting my build.gradle to kotlin but this gives me the error

```
Plugin [id: 'kotlin-android'] was not found in any of the following sources
```

This is how I added Kotlin to my build.gradle file (Module :app)

```
plugins { 

id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'
id 'kotlin-kapt'



buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.60'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

This is what my Cart class CartItems.java

```
package com.example.nourish;

import androidx.room.ColumnInfo;
import androidx.room.Dao;
import androidx.room.Delete;
import androidx.room.Entity;
import androidx.room.Insert;
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey;
import androidx.room.Query;

import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class CartItems {
    @PrimaryKey
    public int uid;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    public String name;

    @ColumnInfo(name="des")
    public String des;

    @ColumnInfo(name="price")
    public String price;

    @ColumnInfo(name="numItems")
    public String numItems;

    @Dao
    public interface CartDoa{
        @Query("SELECT * FROM CartItems")
        List<CartItems> getAll();

        @Insert
        void insertAll(CartItems... items);

        @Delete
        void delete(CartItems items);


    }


}
```

This is what my CartDatabase.java looks like

```
package com.example.nourish;

import androidx.room.RoomDatabase;

public abstract class CartDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract CartItems.CartDoa cartDoa();

}
```

This is how I've implemented it

```
CartDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),
        CartDatabase.class, "CartDatabase").build();
CartItems.CartDoa cartDoa = db.cartDoa();
List<CartItems> cartItems = cartDoa.getAll();
```

I just need help setting Rooms up and making sure I'm using it properly

If someone could let me if there is a way to add Rooms and implement rooms without Kotlin or help me fix my method I would be very grateful.

Thank you for any answers

Comment: Did you forget to add @Database annotation in CradDatabase.java?

Comment: @Database(entities = {CartItems.class}, version = 1)

Comment: “ my build.gradle file is in Java and not Kotlin” This doesn’t make sense. The only language supported by a build.gradle file is Groovy. If you want to use Kotlin, you need to name the file build.gradle.kts. But that won’t change the capabilities of your project configuration.

Answer (score 0):

buildscrpit block is written in build.gradle(Project level)

Comment: I keep getting this error Cannot find implementation for com.example.nourish.CartDatabase. CartDatabase_Impl does not exist

Comment: I've added buildscript block and kotlin-kapt to my module app and its still not working